# How can I store the Unit in which the User is performing an action (incident, order) in service now

Tags: backend, servicenow

I am trying to learn more about ServiceNow and I have following task:

I need to store the unit in which the User is at the moment where he makes an order, or creates an incident. Can you maybe tell me how this is done? Or where can I make this changes?

As an example. An user orders 2 Notebooks. The user is inside of  more than just one Unit. When he places the order, for me should be visible in which unit he was when he placed the order.

Thank you in advanced and I am grateful for all answers.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "Unit"? It's unclear if you intend this to mean something like a specific UI Form or a Catalog Item.

Comment: So in ServiceNow you can add a company to a User and in the company you can add Units:And these units i have to store. Or let's take the provider contract or oder cycle id, i think the process should be the same.

Comment: Are you referring to the department the user is in at the time he placed an order?